# Is there any way to debug gnome-epub-thumbnailer?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thumbnails, logs, epub

I have been trying to use `gnome-epub-thumbnailer` in Ubuntu 23.04. The program installs & I am able to run `gnome-epub-thumbnailer -s 1024 test.epub out.png` successfully, but even after `rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/` and `nautilus -q`, my `epubs` remain stubbornly non-thumbnailed.

I replaced the `Exec` portion of `/usr/share/thumbnailers/gnome-epub-thumbnailer.thumbnailer` with a shell script that prints the arguments before passing them to `gnome-epub-thumbnailer` and the return status after it completes. I don't know where to find these logs though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I corrected the version to 23.04.

Comment: This might be far fetched, but do you have your files with broken modified time like January 1970? If you can execute the script correctly then the problem is either in nautilus (Files) or libgnome-desktop. I can give you a way to debug those without reeking havoc in your system with flatpaks but it will require several gigabytes to install.